# What is "milepost"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I was reading some business article and I found the word **"milepost"**. I was looking for it in dictionaries but the only thing I can find is the word "milestone" which is known to me.

> A **milestone** is a significant event in your life. Often a milestone marks the start of a new chapter. For example, the day you graduated from high school was a milestone in your life.

so what is *milepost*? Is it synonym to *milestone*?

Comment: A great tip. While searching on Google, search like this: 'x' meaning. And, it'll show the definition. In your case, search 'milepost meaning'. Searching is also a trick! ;)

Comment: We would need to see the context. The word could be used like *milestone* or differently. (https://www.google.com/search?q=old+roman+milepost+image&num=20&newwindow=1&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI7qmPxcORxgIVx1qMCh34IgZf&biw=1379&bih=861)

Comment: [macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/milepost), [milepost in Googlet](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22milepost%22&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search&channel=fe&client=browser-ubuntu&hl=ru&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=X69-VZOWMYG5sAGo-YHQCA#newwindow=1&channel=fe&hl=ru&q=%22milepost%22+meaning)

Comment: not my downvote, but the logic of Katarina Kacu is hard to understand. :-) What's the point in asking something without context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - in that context, a milepost is the same as a milestone, although here in the UK, 'milepost' is not very common; milestone being more widely used.

Comment: In which context? Did you see business context involving the word "milepost" here?

Comment: Yes - in the original question.

Comment: Although the difference may not be as big as in the UK, *milestone* is significantly more common here in America, too.  [In the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA), I found a ratio of 18:1 in favor of *milestone*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=40354758), while [the British National Corpus (BNC) showed a ratio of 50:1](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=40354760).  I didn't look to see if the usage of the words differed at all, by the way.